# Splitting by two delimiters PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having issues splitting by two delimiters in PHP. I have the following text and I want to be able to split by the "," then split further by the "|".

```
Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available
```

So the end result would be for me to be able to determine whether it's set to paused or available, and from there filter out so I only get paused values.

```
$phoneurl = "Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available";
$array = explode(",", $phoneurl);

foreach ($array as $value) {
$split = explode("|", $value);
    echo $value[0];
}
```

However when I try and echo $value[0] it simply echoes the first digit of each value.

I'm lost. Please help! :(

Comment: $value[0] contains the first character of the $value you are looping inside $array. You need $split[0] to contain the first word, since that's the variable you assigned the explode("|") to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach ($array as $index => $value) 
 {
     $split = explode("|", $value);
      echo $split[0];
 }
```

try this one.

Comment: Done. Silly 10 minute delay! :(

Answer (score 1):

That will be

```
$result = array_map(function($item)
{
   return explode('|', $item);
}, explode(',', $string));
```

-i.e. first we're splitting array by `,` and then applying `explode()` with `|` to each element of it via `array_map()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$phoneurl = "Someone Name1|paused,Someone Name2|paused,Someone Name3|paused,Someone Name4|paused,Someone Name5|paused,Someone Name6|available,Someone Name7|available,Someone Name8|available";
$array = explode(",", $phoneurl);

foreach ($array as $value) {
$split = explode("|", $value);
if ($split[1]=="paused")
    {   
    echo $split[0];
    echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

I have added a number to "someone name".

your final results are in `table split`. not in `table value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$phoneurl = "Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|paused,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available,Someone Name|available";
$array = explode(",", $phoneurl);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $split = explode("|", $value);
    if($split[1] == "paused" ){
     echo $split[0].'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should echo $split instead of $value.